# usb0 network interface doesn't get up

Tags: ssh, usb, ethernet

I have connected an embedded board to a `usb0` interface of a Linux machine to establish a `ssh` connection to it.

`ifconfig` tells me:

```
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:43:4D:AA:E8:5A
          inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

But it is not "RUNNING". How can I start the interface? Is there a driver missing? `lsusb` finds the device. The device itself runs Yocto Linux.

Comment: `usb0` can refer to many different things - the output of `ethtool -i usb0` would help in identifying the actual driver in use. The interface is already UP, so it *wants* to work, but if it's not RUNNING, that means it is *not able* to work yet. The missing requirement is something specific to the driver and/or underlying hardware.

Comment: is the `usb0` interface provided by USB Gadge framework ?

Answer (score 0):

When you star kernel, have you seen some message similar as below. If yes, suppose you already have the linux driver correctly installed.

> asix 3-3:1.0 eth0: register 'asix' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, ASIX
>   AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:c0:d0:5e

Next,  please use the following command to check link status, make sure the physical link is up and connection is good. Please help to paste your test log, I can get more information based on your setup.

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 16
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pg
        Wake-on: p
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:C6:C0:D0:5E
          inet addr:10.0.0.143  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1898 (1.8 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he was asking how to bring up the `usb0` interface:

`sudo ifconfig usb0 up`

Root has to run this, sudo optional depending who you are.  You can find out by `whoami`.

Comment: The device is already UP but not RUNNING.